# Where should I define event and eventhandler for ItemView?

Tags: marionette

I have a simple CollectionView and ItemView as follow :

```
var CommentView = Mariontete.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: 'li'
});

var CommentsView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView: CommentView,
  events : {
    'click li' : 'onCommentClick'
  },
  onCommentClick: function(){}
});
```

My question is that where should I define event and event handler for CommentView, shoud I put it in Commentview? or CommentsView? as above?

If I put it in CommentView as follow, Do I loose performance since it attaches event on every "li" tag? :

```
var CommentView = Mariontete.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  events : {
    'click' : 'onCommentClick'
  },
  onCommentClick: function(){}
});

var CommentsView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
  itemView: CommentView  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - there's benefits and drawbacks to each approach. Using event delegation (as in your first example) allows you to use a single handler for all comment click events. However, since you're no longer operating in the context of the original view, the code can get a little tricky if you need specific knowledge from that view. Attaching event handlers directly to each view resolves this but can certainly result in degraded performance - especially if there's lots of items in your collection.

There's a couple of ways to attack this problem. First thing to consider is how many items you expect to have in your item view. I generally don't feel comfortable with view-level event handlers if my collection is >20 items, but under that you should be fine.

The next thing to consider is what information you need access to while handling the event. If you don't need any item-specific knowledge, then there's really no reason to attach a handler to each view.

Finally, if you've got lots of items and you need view-specific information things can get tricky. Typically I see people stuff model data into `data-xxx` properties in that view's element, but that seems just as clunky to me as adding explicit event handlers. The approach that I use is to leverage jQuery's `index()` method to determine the index of the itemview that was clicked, then use that to locate the view. Then I can work with the view directly.

Here's an example that should work with your code, assuming there's nothing inside your LI's:

```
handleClick: function(e) {
    var ix = $(e.target).index(),
        view = this.children.findByIndex(ix),
        model = view.model.toJSON();
    ... do something amazing here
}
```

If your itemview's are more complicated then the event's target might end up being a child element. In this case you'll need to do something like `$(e.target).parent('li').index()` instead to locate the correct root `$el`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the answer that I was expecting !!

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be simple: Take care of one's own business.

You have not stated the purpose of clicking `li`. Maybe you want to expand the li to see details, or want to launch a management dialog. For whatever reason I can guess, this action looks only about a specific itemView but has nothing to do with collectionView.

So, just simply watch this event in itemView. Don't bother collectionView at all.

For performance, I don't think it's something should be considered in this case. Even if you watch collectionView, the event listeners are finally attached to those specific DOM element, there is no difference.

Comment: I'm not following your last sentence - there is a difference. If the event listener is defined on the `CollectionView`, then there's only one listener. If it's defined in the `ItemView` then there's going to be one for *each item in the collection*.

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta, I have not gone depth about that statement, maybe you are right. However, in this case I don't think performance is important. If an event is about the view, the the view should handle it, not collection view. If the event is about add/remove/reset/anything about collection, then collection view handle it. It's simple and don't need any fancy solution to take care of performance.